# ioS Scroll View with dynamic table View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I want to create a “ViewController” Scene with a “Scroll View” and in this view there should be a “Table View” at the top,    1 “segmented Control and 2 tables at the bottom.
The “Segmented Control” should switch the bottom table views.
Like in this picture:

[image]

My problem with this scene is that the table should have a dynamic height.

I need the bar over the complete page and not in the individual tables.
Is it possible to create such a scene and if yes, which constraints do I have to set?
I hope you can help me! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`tableView` inside `scrollView` is a disastrous idea, because

1. `tableView` itself have its own `scrollView`.
2. Scrolling will be very sticky and it may freeze UI.

The best solution comes on my mind is to take single `tableView` and manage multiple `sections`.

The Green portion will be your first section.

Segment control will be second.

and blue section will be third.

In this way you can achieve both dynamic height as well as single scroll bar condition.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It's pity that it does not work. 

Your solution works, Thanks a bunch!